# python webscraper called by excel vba : problems in interaction

Tags: python, excel, vba, selenium

I will describe you a problem of interaction EXCEL VBA Script calling a python webscraper script, to collect an visualize financial data from the n-tv website.
It is an exercise and only private interest for me , to understand, where my mistake is.  I am a beginner in programming and not a professional, so please do not be irritated by my probably very poor program style. I am just learning and this is an exercise.
First I show you my python web scraper Script based on selenium:

Screenshot
[enter image description here][1]
+
Text of code:

```
"""
Spyder Editor
This is a temporary script file.
"""
import time
print("ich bin überfordert")    
time.sleep(3)

print("import ausgeführt")

time.sleep(3)
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\Google\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http:\\www.n-tv.de')
time.sleep(5)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sp_message_iframe_532515"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.refresh()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stock__currency')
link[0].click()
time.sleep(3)
tab2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tableholder")
rows = tab2[3].find_elements_by_class_name('linked')
datei = open('textdatei.txt','a')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    zeichen = ""
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
        zeichen = zeichen + col.text + "\t" 
    print(zeichen)
    datei.write(zeichen + "\n")

datei.close()
driver.close()
```

It is based on selenium, clicks away a cookie button in an iframe, links to the target finanzdata DAX an reads out those data in a file.txt.

Then the text of the calling EXCEL VBA Script:

```
Sub Textdatei_Einlesen()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim TextAusDatei As String
Dim Zähler As Long
Dim Tabelle As Worksheet
PythonExe = """C:\Python39\python.exe"""
PythonScript = "C:\Users\annet\ScrapeTest.py"
'PythonScript = "D:\PYTHON-Test\shell_excel.py"
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, 1, True
End Sub
```

The VBA Script is working in the kind, that a simple test python program “shell_excel.py” is called by excel, runs without problem an so far it seemed all ok.

Above As you can see, the small “shell_excel.py” counter test script is executed correctly.
Following the source code of shell_excel.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
import time
print("ich bin überfordert")

for i in range(0,10):
    print(str(i))
    time.sleep(i)
    print("sek: " + str(i))

print("import ausgeführt")
```

But the Problems arises, if the Excel VBA calls the python scraper script:

As you can see, the web scraper is called and started like the first print commad of python script.
But the rest of the lines of the python source code is not executed.  After a ca half a second the prompt shell is closed without any calling of the webdriver or something else as an effect, even without any error message.

As you can see by screenshot, the scraper script is running until the first print command, but at the first imports it is finished without any result and effect.

I think there must be problems by importing selenium etc.
And that I do not understand, because if i call and run my scrape script alone under xSpider, it works fine.
I know, there would be other ways to get the data into excel sheet, but I want in ideal case only open excel, press vba run button, the scraping an other processes are starting and automaticalliy excel takes the scraped data from txt file to make graphics.
Has anyone an idea, where the problem in my python environment coud be ?
Remark again, the scraper alone works, the excel vba script alone works, the small python script to test is called correctly by excel vba, but if i switch to the selenium based script it is not executed at the import parts.

Has anyone an idea ?

I am very sorry, the screenshot as jpg files are here not imported, i don not why, it seems i have not the rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python script worked sometimes but not always so I added some WebDriverWait blocks and that seems to have fixed it. The VBA is much the same except I used Exec instead of Run to capture the output.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Textdatei_Einlesen()

    Const PyExe = "C:\Python39\python.exe"
    Const PyScript = "C:\Users\annet\ScrapeTest.py"
    
    Dim objShell As Object, objScript As Object
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objScript = objShell.Exec("""" & PyExe & """ " & PyScript)
    
    MsgBox objScript.StdOut.ReadAll(), vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

python

```py
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

URL = 'https://www.n-tv.de'
DRIVERPATH = r'C:\Program Files\Google\chromedriver.exe'
 
def logit(s):
   log.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ") + s + "\n")

# create logfile
logfile = sys.path[0] + '\\' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S') + ".log"
log = open(logfile,'a')

# webdriver
s = Service(DRIVERPATH)
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=op)

print("Getting " + URL)
driver.get(URL)

try:
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until \
    (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="sp_message_iframe_532515"]')))
    logit("IFrame is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    logit("Loading IFrame took too much time!")
    quit()

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.refresh()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until \
    (EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'stock__currency')))
    logit("Page is ready!")  
    
except TimeoutException:
    logit("Loading Page took too much time!")
    driver.quit()
    quit()

link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'stock__currency')  
link[0].click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until \
    (EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'tableholder')))
    logit("Table is ready!")  
    
except TimeoutException:
    logit("Loading Table took too much time!")
    driver.quit()
    quit()

# find table
tab2 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"tableholder")
rows = tab2[3].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'linked')

# create text file
datei = open('textdatei.txt','a')

# write to text file
for row in rows:
    logit(row.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'td')
    zeichen = ""
    for col in cols:
        zeichen = zeichen + col.text + "\t" 
    datei.write(zeichen + "\n")

# exit
datei.close()
log.close()
driver.quit()
print("Ended see logfile " + logfile)
quit()
```