# Run python script stored in excel cell

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have excel workbook and in a sheet in range("A1"), suppose I have this line into the cell

```
print('Hello World')
```

Is there a way to run this python script from the cell from VBA itself?

Thanks a lot @Anu

```
Sub Test()
    Dim PID
    PID = Shell("python -c '" & Range("A1").Value & "'", vbNormalNoFocus)
End Sub
```

How can I print the output to the immediate window in VBE?

I tried to put a python script in a cell but this doesn't give me the correct output (No errors appeared but the images are not converted to Photos/New folder

```
import os
from PIL import Image

dirname_read = r"C:/Users/Future/Desktop/Photos/Demo/"
dirname_write = r"C:/Users/Future/Desktop/Photos/New/"
names = os.listdir(dirname_read)
count = 0

for name in names:
    img=Image.open(dirname_read+name)
    name=name.split(".")
    if name[-1] == "png" or name[-1] == "jpeg" or name[-1] == "PNG":
        name[-1] = "jpg"
        name = str.join(".", name)
        to_save_path = dirname_write + name
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        img.save(to_save_path)
        count+=1     
    else:
        name = str.join(".", name)
        to_save_path = dirname_write + name
        img.save(to_save_path)

images = [file for file in os.listdir(dirname_write) if file.endswith(('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'PNG'))]
for image in images:
    img = Image.open(dirname_write + image)
    img = img.resize((360, 540), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
    rgb_img.save(dirname_write + image)

print("Total Converted Count: ", count)
```

Comment: If there is a python interpreter installed on the same computer, then yes, you can pass the python code to the interpreter through shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you show me a simple example, please?

Comment: Does the python code need to be in cell A1 ? . if so, you could write the cell vaue to  `~tmp.py` file then execute it using `Wscript.Shell` see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338662/)

Comment: It is also not nice to edit your question by adding new requirements into it after receiving an answer for the original question! If you have a new question, then I suggest to accept the answer for this question an open a new question with the additional requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA you should be able to run the python shell. this way you can pass the code into it. `python -c 'print(f"test")'` the `-c` flag allows passing of code as a string.

EDIT: the VBA code would looks a lot like this `PID = Shell("python -c 'Range("A1").Value'", vbNormalNoFocus)` (I'm winging this part since VBA is not my primary language)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give me more details? I need the steps to do such a solution. Will I use `Shell`?

Comment: ya you would use `Shell` in VBA, but VBA is not me main language so you may have to do some more research around that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added it to the the question and there is one more question related to it?

Comment: ya sorry, i dont know a lot of VBA, so i cant really help you there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great support. Just one last question for you: How can I keep the console of the command prompt open?

Comment: i think for that you either have to pass focus onto the shell command; Or run the VBA script from an already opened cmd. Once again, VBA is not something im proficient in so I'm not going to be much help.

Comment: I have used `vbNormalFocus` but the window disappeared.!!

Comment: try running the VBA script from an open CMD

Comment: But this is not the target of my question, I need to use VBA code itself to run the python code stored in a cell (the python script in a cell)

Comment: @YasserKhalil please, do not ask follow-up questions in comments, that's not really nice! If you have an additional question, even if it is linked to the current one, you need to ask it in a separate question!